# Is there a way to stay logged into StackOverflow when accessing from more than one device?

Tags: support, openid, login

If I log into Stack Overflow with my work computer, then log in with another device, when I come back to my Work Computer I have been logged out of Stack Overflow.

I also have noticed (in the last few months) that my login lasts only a day at most.  (So I have to log in daily) Even if I have not shut down or connected with any other device.

Is this normal?  I used to be able to not have to log in quite so frequently.

Comment: What browsers? You probably increased security settings, blocking cookies etc.

Comment: It works for me. I'm logged in on my Windows laptop and on my iPad, and I stay logged in for days at a time.

Comment: Chrome keeps me logged in from all my devices.

Answer (score 2):

That is not normal - you should be able to be logged in on multiple devices and a log-in should persist for several months.

My current usr cookie is good until June of next year.  I'm logged in on 2 PCs, one Mac, and two mobile devices.

Comment: what do you do with 2 PCs, one Mac, and two mobile devices... on so ?

Comment: How do you tell how long the cookie should persist?

Comment: @NullPointer - Work desktop, home desktop, laptop, tablet, and mobile phone. So many internets, so little time.

Comment: @Vaccano - Using the Web Dev toolbar for Firefox, I can view cookie details, including expiry date.